# C# - SpecFlow - MsTest - Encode - Language accentuation in auto-generated class feature

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automated-tests, mstest, specflow

Using:

1. Specflow version: 2.3.2
2. Visual Studio: Enterprise 2017
3. .Net framework > .NET 4

I was developing automated tests using SpecFlow + MsTest + C# and, since the beginning, I wrote with the Portuguese language the features files. Suddenly, the auto-generated files stopped to recognize the Portuguese accentuation and broke the link between the features files and steps definition files.

The language it's configured as `<language feature="pt-BR"/>` on Specflow configuration.

I tried after this problem add `<bindingCulture name="pt-BR" />` and not worked too.

I tried to set the language inside the feature file with the `#language: pt-BR` but it created the auto-generated file with the same problems.

The Visual Studio was in English, but I tried to change to Portuguese and these don't fix my issue.

Does anyone have any idea what it might be?

Comment: This comment on https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1205 helps me:

"This option can be set at Visual Studio Specflow Options. Tools > Options > SpecFlow > General > Code Behind File Generation > OutOfProcess
If I change to appDomain working fine"

Comment: This bug is already fixed and we will release a new version of the extension in this week.